# Validation tooltip Does not exist

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, styles, tooltip

Im working on an application with validation. However, everything was doing great untill i installed this theme : [Theme](http://brianlagunas.com/free-metro-light-and-dark-themes-for-wpf-and-silverlight-microsoft-controls/).

Everything is nice and all, but when i get an validation error, i get this exception:

> 'validationTooltip' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip'.

I can simply remove where this is called. but im also wondering how this looks and might want to add this.

Anyone has an idea how to solve this?

I'll provide anything you guys desire around this question. code, styles etc.

**UPDATE**

Now that i commented all the code that gave an error. My own validation template isnt show though.

**UPDATE2**
I fixed that it shows back my own validation template. full code of his validation is below. if i forgot something. just tell me. thanks in advance

**CODE**

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Valid" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
                                              </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>

<Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ValidationErrorElement}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Template="{StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplate}">
                                    <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <System:Boolean>true</System:Boolean>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                    </ToolTip.Triggers>
                                </ToolTip>
                            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        </Border>
```

Comment: I hope this will help https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/134 .Here They have suggested to comment your ToolTipTrigger .But let me tell you my company UX team is also using the same way and it is working absolutely fine and is in Silverlight.